# How to export the data from Progress OpenEdge Database Server

Tags: export, openedge, progress-db

We are working on a migration of a system, currently they use Progress OpenEdge, and we need to export the data from the production database to carry out tests and know how to do it in the best way when the migration is carried out. We have investigated that with Data Administration Tool it is possible, but we have doubts, what is the best way to export the data? Can we export the data from the server in production without stopping it? Can the information be exported from a backup?

Any help is appreciated in advance
Thank you.

Comment: What is the target database for the eventual migration? What is the Progress version you're running on?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot export data directly from a backup.  The only thing that you can do with a backup is to restore it.

Yes, you can export from a live production db (or a restored backup).

Exporting from a shutdown or quiescent database is usually preferred because it gives you a well defined point in time for consistency.

Exporting for migration purposes probably also involves transformation of the data.  Unless the new system is an exact replica of the old there are probably some fairly significant data conversions required.  Those could be done in various ways.  “Best” will depend on your unstated requirements.  There is also probably a lot of data that you do not need to migrate.

A few factors that you might want to consider when thinking about migrating the data:

- Do you understand the business problem?  Or are you "just" technical help hired to move bits from point A to point B?
- What is your level of understanding of the source data model?
- How about the target?  How well do you understand that?
- Do you have access to OpenEdge compiler licenses?  If you do not then you cannot filter and/or transform the data at the source.  At best you can just dump whole tables.
- Has SQL access been setup for the source database?  If it has then you might prefer to use some sort of ODBC based tooling to extract the data.

You will have to decide what extract method is “best” or not depending on your capabilities and the requirements of the situation.  There is no one-size fits all answer for "best".